# CastClassException on Custom View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

When I try to `findViewById()` on my custom view I keep getting a `ClassCastException`. I've tried so many things that I'm sure I've botched the code now!

To make sure I'm not going insane I stripped down the classes to their bare minimum inorder to find what was wrong.

I'm new to android programming and I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

**This is `BaseImageView` an extended view class.**

```
package com.company.product.client.android.gui.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

public class BaseImageView
    extends View
{
    public BaseImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

**This is `LiveImageView` an extension of the `BaseImageView` class.**

```
package com.company.product.client.android.gui.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class LiveImageView
    extends BaseImageView
{
    public LiveImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

**Here is the Layout `my_view.xml`.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">


    <View
        class="com.company.product.client.android.gui.views.LiveImageView"
        android:id="@+id/lvImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**And here is the onCreate in my Activity `LiveViewActivity`.**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.my_view);
        final LiveImageView lvImage = (LiveImageView) findViewById(R.id.lvImage);
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate() Exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Finally, this is stack trace.**

```
02-11 17:25:24.829: ERROR/LiveViewActivity(1942): onCreate() Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View
02-11 17:25:24.839: WARN/System.err(1942): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View
02-11 17:25:24.839: WARN/System.err(1942):     at com.company.product.client.android.gui.screen.LiveViewActivity.onCreate(LiveViewActivity.java:26)
02-11 17:25:24.839: WARN/System.err(1942):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-11 17:25:24.849: WARN/System.err(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
02-11 17:25:24.849: WARN/System.err(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
02-11 17:25:24.849: WARN/System.err(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-11 17:25:24.849: WARN/System.err(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
02-11 17:25:24.859: WARN/System.err(1942):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 17:25:24.859: WARN/System.err(1942):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-11 17:25:24.859: WARN/System.err(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-11 17:25:24.869: WARN/System.err(1942):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 17:25:24.869: WARN/System.err(1942):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-11 17:25:24.869: WARN/System.err(1942):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-11 17:25:24.869: WARN/System.err(1942):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-11 17:25:24.879: WARN/System.err(1942):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using in Layout xml files, your custom view should be:

```
<com.company.product.client.android.gui.views.LiveImageView
    android:layout_width="..."
    ...
/>
```

Moreover, make sure you define the other two variants of constructors for views:

```
public BaseImageView(Context, AttributeSet);
public BaseImageView(Context, AttributeSet, int);
```

Since the layout inflater actually need that two variants to create the instance.

Comment: This will work, (the defStyle constructor parameter type should be an int,) but the reason the code posted in the question does not is that `View` is not the same as `view` in the tag name. `view` (lowercase) lets you specify the class name using the attribute. `View` refers to the Android framework class `android.view.View`.

Comment: Thanks xandy and adamp. I changed the View to view and added the two constructor variants and it worked.  
I tried it in my un-stripped down version and I got a NullPointerException and then InflateException but that turned out to be an error in the constructor which cause the object to not be initialized.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this before, use a lowercase `<view>` tag:

`<view
        class="com.company.product.client.android.gui.views.LiveImageView" ... />`

This is from [Android's docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying) item 4:

`<view
  class="com.android.notepad.NoteEditor$MyEditText" 
  id="@+id/note" ...`

Comment: I think I will never find this mistake by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your XML declaration

```
   <com.company.product.client.android.gui.views.LiveImageView        
    android:id="@+id/lvImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Or it can be due to a bug.

Workaround to fix: Assign some new 'id' value for the CustomView in Layout XML and findViewById().